# Can I replace a damaged firmware of a 3D printer based on Arduino Mega?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, firmware

I have acquired a second hand 3D printer, the GEEETECH I3 Pro B. The previous owner tried to change the firmware but he made a mistake and he bricked the board.

I want to substitute the firmware of the board (which is an Arduino Mega 2560 based board). Do you think is possible if the board doesn't respond to the controls?

I have inquired and found an open source software called Marlin I want to use to restore the printer.

If you have an advice or you think that I can do it in any ways tell me.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: I'm only familiar with flashing phones and computers, but it depends on if the method to do the flash will still work on the board in it's current condition.

Comment: it's hard to truly brick a mega, the bootloader is separate from the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to diagnose the board without hands on experience. It is even more difficult if you get a board that has been "updated/upgraded" by a previous owner leaving it not in working condition.

But, there are at least 2 solutions.

1. You could buy a new printer controller board, upload new firmware and connect all connectors.
2. You could try to [burn a new bootloader](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/7777) onto your current board and [upload a new version of the firmware](http://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/install.html).